# redis not connected with django-redis

Tags: python, django, django-redis

i have set a query set in my cache as :

```
cache.set('person',Lecture_Detail.objects.all())
```

in my views:

```
from django.core.cahe import cache
t3=datetime.datetime.now()
list(Lecture_Detail.objects.all())
t5 = datetime.datetime.now()
print "time before",(t5 - t3)
g = cache.get('person')
t4 = datetime.datetime.now()
print "time after",(t4 - t5)
g = cache.get('person')
t6 = datetime.datetime.now()
print "time after",t6-t4
g = cache.get('person')
t7 = datetime.datetime.now()
print "time after",t7-t6
```

when i exexute this its output is:

```
time before 0:00:00.014256
time after 0:00:01.366022
time after 0:00:01.552436
time after 0:00:01.433049
```

so i think that my redis is not connected with django-redis .
my settings are:

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "redis_cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://127.0.0.1:6379:1",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "redis_cache.client.DefaultClient",
        }
    }
}
```

so plz me suggest me something .. thanx in advance..

Comment: Where do you run your Redis instance? Same server or somewhere else? Is `queryset` loaded all att once or is it lazy? (That is: does it fetch all rows or does it only fetch rows as you read them?). How large of a difference is it? You can edit your question to include answers to these questions.

Answer (score 5):

When you write `queryset=Lecture_Detail.objects.all()` database sql query is not yet executed.
When the query is executed:

1. iteration
2. slicing
3. Pickling/Caching
4. repr()
5. len()
6. list()
7. bool()

Read more about this here: [When QuerySets are evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated). So in your example database query would be executed on line `cache.set('person',queryset)`

You can test by change line from `queryset=Lecture_Detail.objects.all()` to `list(queryset=Lecture_Detail.objects.all())`

Comment: as you have suggest me now i'm applying following operation on both condition (after getting data from database and from cache) :

t1=datetime.datetime.now()

g = Lecture_Detail.objects.all()

name = g.filter(lecture_name = 'Chemistry')

length = len(name)

t2=datetime.datetime.now()

 bt still time difference is very much its about : 

"without cache 0:00:00.903429 with cache 0:00:02.490702 "

so please suggest me something..

Comment: How many records in the table? How many records after filtering?

Comment: 101006 records are in table and 50000 afer filtering

Comment: I tried myself, but I used filesystem caching, and got similar results: without cache 0:00:00.246513 and wich cache 0:00:00.666614

Answer (score 0):

Actually my mistake was that i was using django cache instead of using redis cache .... to use redis we have to do something like this :

first set data from your python shell or view as:

```
import redis
r=redis.StrictRedis()
r.set('person',Lecture_Detail.objects.all())
```

to get data from redis cache:

```
import redis

r=redis.StrictRedis()
t3=datetime.datetime.now()
list(Lecture_Detail.objects.all())
t5 = datetime.datetime.now()
print "time before",(t5 - t3)
g = r.get('person')
t4 = datetime.datetime.now()
print "time after",(t4 - t5)
```

and now the time difference is just unbelieveable